# HTML5 ¿frame? for cross-origin request

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

For an app that runs at a different port than 80, let's say 1234, I must insert a snippet to display latest forum threads. Forum runs at port 80, so I get cross-domain errors when loading php stuff. Is there any equivalent of the old html frames so I can load a html file in port 80 inside the port 1234 app??

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald — Why? That won't do a thing for frames.

Comment: @Quentin I must have misunderstood the question, I thought he wanted to get around CORs

Comment: Yes. I don't need a frame specifically if I can do it other way.

Comment: But my problem isn't solved yet.